# What's the time complexity of std::string::contains in C++23?

Tags: c++, c++23

The cppreference says `std::string::contains` is coming out,
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/contains

but there is no runtime requirement. Is it guaranteed to run in linear time? (say, using KMP algorithm in implementation) or quadratic time?

I've tried to find it in the current C++ standard draft (http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4849.pdf), but I couldn't find the reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Going by [the most recent draft](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/string.contains), `contains` is:

> Equivalent to:
>
> ```
> return basic_string_view<charT, traits>(data(), size()).contains(x);
> ```

With the [`string_view` function being](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/string.view.ops#26):

> Equivalent to: `return find(x) != npos;`

Since equality testing an integer with `basic_string_view::npos` is a constant-time operation, the time complexity [will be that of `basic_string_view::find`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/string.view.find#1):

> Member functions in this subclause have complexity O(size() * str.size()) at worst, although implementations should do better.

Answer (score 0):

The [proposal (P1679)](https://wg21.link/p1679) indicates that `contains` is equivalent to `find(x) != npos`.

At worst, the complexity could be O(size() * str.size()).  At best the operation can be performed at compile time if both strings are known since both `std::string::contains` and `std::string_view::contains` are `constexpr` methods.

Note, currently (GCC 11) only `std::string_view` has `constexpr` functionality in libstdc++.

Trivial constexpr example: https://godbolt.org/z/Ejosx43bM

The commit adding contains() to libstdc++ for GCC 11: https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=commitdiff;h=f004d6d9fab9fe732b94f0e7d254700795a37f30